# How to update a table row with save button using .ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, jtemplate

I have a table which has one row and only one cell will be editable.  I have accomplished this with the following code.

```
$("td#effEndDate").click(function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass("edit")) {
                var value = jQuery.trim($(this).html());
                $(this).html("<input id=\"txtEdit\" type=\"text\" value=\"" + value + "\" />");
                $(this).addClass("edit");
                $("#txtEdit").focus();
            }
        });
```

Now this is the part where i'm stuck.

After the field is updated a save button must be clicked to call the proper .ajax method to update the database. But how can I compare the previous value to the current value on a button press? Since i'm not using the onblur property where I could have saved the old value and passed it to the update function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

- Pass the variable around in between functions
- Make the variable global

if you want the variable global do not use the "var" keyword

Change:

```
var value = jQuery.trim($(this).html());
```

To this:

```
value = jQuery.trim($(this).html());
```

**Edit**

If the click function is getting hit more then once before a page refresh and assuming you want to keep a copy of the original table rows you can try this. Save a copy of the original table in a variable then you can query the original table for the html using the ID number. Here is a quick mock

first store the table in a variable upon the page loading. This will save an original copy of the table

```
 //get a copy of the table
 var GetCopyofOriginalTable = function() {
      var TableToBeCopied = $('the appropriate selector');
      CopyOfTable = JQuery.extend(true, {}, TableToBeCopied);  //Notice no var, its global
 }

 //Now store the variale
 GetCopyofOriginalTable();

 var FindTableRowByID = function(trID) {
      return $('table:has(tr#' + trID));
 }
```

Now you can loop through the new table test its value agaisnt the old table. This methed make use alot of memory depending on how big the table is.

Comment: Thanks, yes that does work. But if I wanted to make more than one cell editable the .click function will be called more than once thus wiping out the previous value. Is there a way to save the whole <tr> and store it into an object or something and then compare it to the new values?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the original value somewhere in a variable, and compare the two in the submission function before sending the `.ajax` call.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The original value is already being saved in the third line of the code.
   var value = jQuery.trim($(this).html());
But this value is not visible to other functions. How could I save the value so it would be visible to other functions?